# Nginx multiple subdomains with reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, domain, reverse-proxy, subdomain

I have a few apps running from the same server on different ports, I want to host them on different subdomains, I'm using Nginx, I can get it to work with 1 app, but once I add a second server block both of them get a "connection time out" page in my browser
this is what I'm using right now:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

this works, but If I add another one, both of them stop working.

When I have both it is like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name sub.domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
server {
listen 80;
server_name sub2.domain.com;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing works anymore" doesn't really mean anything. You need to be specific about what happens (or didn't happen) and what the configuration was.

Comment: Edited, but I get a connection not found page in my browser.

Comment: I can only see one location block. Please include both the working block, and how it looks after it's not working. Please also include for each a curl showing the response code, error message, server logs, etc. We can help you but we need information to do it.

Comment: I added block of the settings when it doesn't work, and I only get a connection timed out in my browser, besides that I don't get any other responses

Comment: Check your DNS records.

Comment: what do I need to look for? or what kind of entry should I have?

Comment: @MichaelHampton what kind of DNS records would I need to check/add? I'm not very familiar with DNS, so I wouldn't know what to do

Comment: Check that the hostname you are having a problem with has the correct IP address. You used [fake information](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963), so nobody else can do that for you.

Comment: had the same problem... was a broken caa entry on my dns